# Ansible unattended installs with apt module

Tags: vagrant, ansible

Is it possible to do unattended install on Debian Wheezy with Ansible apt module? I'm trying to install ActiveMQ.

Comment: generally speaking, yes. What have you tried? Did you get errors?

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by following:

```
 - name: Install ActiveMQ
   apt: name=activemq state=installed update_cache=yes dpkg_options='force-confold,force-confdef'
```